# VBA loop / for each works very slow

Tags: excel, vba

I am using following code, to copy each non blank cells formula and paste it to next cells.
But it works very very slow. Is there any way to make it work faster?

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColName As String
    Dim ColNumber As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CpyFrom As range
    Dim Cell As range
    
    'for each rows
    Set CpyFrom = ActiveSheet.range("L10003:L10054")
    
    
    '~~> Sheet name to format
    Set ws = Sheets("DATA TO FORMAT (2)")
    
    ColName = ws.range("B9").Value2
    ColNumber = range(ColName & 1).Column
    
    '~~> Here is the loop from 0 to col number
    For i = 0 To ColNumber - 13
    
     For Each Cell In CpyFrom
        If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            Cell.Offset(0, i).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula
        End If
    Next Cell
        
        
    Next i
```

Comment: one cause could be calculation occuring with each "copy" operation. Set calculation to manual and see if it goes faster. If it does, you can add this to your code. See tip #1 here: https://vbacompiler.com/optimize-vba-code/

Comment: I also had to turn calculations into manual, which greatly sped it up. Typically if you are selecting cells each time, that can also slow it down.

Comment: Thank you so much for that information. I didn't even expected such a big difference.

Comment: Also, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` can make a difference (just do not forget to turn it back on after code finishes and to error handling).

Comment: `Screenupdating` resets itself once your code is finished.

Comment: Now code works super fast.. but it is not updating formulas.. instead I need to click each cell and click enter...

Comment: `Cell.Offset(0, i).Formula = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula`

Comment: Thank you, but still result same.. it only shows formula result when I click on formula and click enter..

Answer (score 0):

May you need to use this  *Application.Calculation = xlManual* in the first of your code and Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic in your last code .
May it help